# How to secure PHP code for uploading avatar images?

Tags: php, vulnerability, source-code

I can bypass an avatar upload image verification process and upload a PHP file or any other extension binding a valid jpeg image.

This is the code:

```
if ($image->valid()) {
            $mimeType = $image->mimeType();
            if ($mimeType !== 'image/jpeg' && $mimeType !== 'image/png') {
                return new DataResponse(
                    ['data' => ['message' => $this->l->t('Unknown filetype')]],
                    Http::STATUS_OK,
                    $headers
                );
            }
```

For example:

1. download image1.jpg
2. as you can see if you open the file image1.jpg file on notepad it hides PHP code `( phpinfo();` function in this case.
3. rename image1.jpg to image1.php, and try to upload it on the avatar upload 
   form. It passes verification.

How to secure this code?

Comment: Check the file extension before the mime type? Is that not an option?

Comment: This may be of use http://nullcandy.com/php-image-upload-security-how-not-to-do-it/

Comment: I don't think anyone can really evaluate the code if you don't include the code... You've left out the most important pieces. Checking the mime type is a good security step *depending on how you calculate the mime type*, which is the part you left out.

Comment: Why not check how phpbb handles file filtering ?

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know what processing is being done, we can't comment on how secure this is.

The only safe way to handle image uploads is:

1) never use the user supplied name/path (but you can store it / include it in output if properly escaped, but never write this back to your filesystem)

2) store the content outside of the document root and mediate all subsequent access via a control script

3) at upload, extract and create the image raster from the file and re-encode this into the file you will be keeping

Comment: Not entirely sure I agree with point 2 (depending on the scenario), and for point 3 I've seen imagemagick used often enough, which has had some pretty serious vulnerabilities in the past, including RCE.

Comment: Yes, software has vulnerabilities - but the lower in the stack you go (in this case a packaged library rather than scripted code) the faster vulnerabilities are identified/fixed and the easier and cheaper is to get the fix deployed.